# How to return a boolean true value when comparing a String with a StringBuilder without using equals?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, equals-operator

I want this code to print **true**. 
I saw this question when passing my OCA7 exam. 
I know the thing about the string pool and all and I also know the difference between [equals() and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

The exam question didn't offer the .equals() option. It only said to figure out a way to make this code to return **true** by comparing a Stringbuilder with a String "==" operator. I had to figure out 1 option among 4 other that all had used the "==". No equals –

```
package test.test;

public class SomeClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcd");

        String str = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(sb.toString() == str);

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Use `.equals()`, because the Strings are not interned.

Comment: The exam question didnt offer the .equals() option. It only required a "==" operator. I had to figure out 1 option among 4 other that all had used the "==". No equals

Comment: @Rahoul what were the choices?

Comment: It was today but I dont remember the choices. There 4 choices

Comment: Why is this question closed? The supposedly duplicated question was different. In this question you Vann not use equals().

Comment: BTW, I could use intern(), so sb.toString().intern() == str.intern() is one possible answer IMO.